# IE7 table colspan fixed width issue

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a problem with IE7 where I have a table with 4 columns and 3 rows. The first column in the first and third row have fixed widths, and the first column in the second row has a colspan of 2. I have set up a fiddle of it, and I just cannot understand what I am doing wrong (other than trying to support IE 7!)

Could anyone tell me how to get the first column to actually be 60px wide?

http://jsfiddle.net/9GNJd/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the CSS "table-layout:fixed;" onto the table element.